# Ansible variable: Can I reference a variable within itself?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am writing roles for an ansible playbook.  In the role I have a `defaults` folder containing a `main.yml` to define default values for the variables the role uses.  Can I cross-reference within the same object?

For example, I have tried the following:

```
scripts_config: 
  host_entry:
    dir: "/foo" 
    file: "{{dir}}/config"
    foo: "{{host_entry.dir}}/foo"
    bar: "{{scripts_config.host_entry.dir}}/bar"
```

None of them work.  I tried each of `file`, `foo` and `bar` one at a time:

- `file` gave *The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
  The error was: 'dir' is undefined*
- `foo` gave *The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'host_entry' is undefined*
- `bar` gave *An unhandled exception occurred while templating*

Is it even possible?

My use case is that I want an object with a directory and several files which would be relative to that in the default set-up.  But if you override the defaults you could specify full paths for one or more of the files, so i don't want the task to assume it's relative.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to self reference a variable to set a default value. Just use the [default filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables).

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    file: "{{ dir | default ('/foo') }}/config" 
  tasks:
    - debug: var=file
```

You can override the default:

```
$ ansible-playbook default.yml -e dir=/changed
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "file": "/changed/config"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Or use the default value:

```
$ ansible-playbook default.yml 
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "file": "/foo/config"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

You can also use `set_fact`. You can change either the base directory for all files or the complete path for each individual file:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact: base="/foo"
      when: base is undefined
    - set_fact: file1={{base}}/file1
      when: file1 is undefined
    - set_fact: file2={{base}}/file2
      when: file2 is undefined
    - debug: var=file1
    - debug: var=file2
```

Comment: Yes, i know you can use default value for the directory.  Point is what I want is actually a set of variables for files, where the default value for the files are all relative to a common parent, but each file path can be overwritten _in it's entirety_.  I want defaults for the files.  Will just repeat the full path in the defaults, it's not that many

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do when I want something of this sort:

```
/parent_dir/
├── dirA/
├── dirB/
├── dirC/
└── dirD/
```

Is addding the following to the role `defaults`

`parent_dir: /parent_dir/`

And then this to the `vars`

```
other_dir_a: "{{ parent_dir }}/dirA"
other_dir_b: "{{ parent_dir }}/dirB"
other_dir_c: "{{ parent_dir }}/dirC"
other_dir_d: "{{ parent_dir }}/dirD"
```

That way your "other" directories/files... will be relative to `{{ parent_dir }}`.

Is this similar to what you want to do?

**Update based on a comment below**

All of these variables are more "important" than role vars:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html

- block vars (only for tasks in block)
- task vars (only for the task)
- include_vars
- set_facts / registered vars
- role (and include_role) params
- include params
- extra vars (always win precedence)

You could use any of them to replace. For example, using extra vars.

`ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -e other_dir_a=/new/path/for/a -e other_dir_b=/new/path/for/b`

If you want to use them all as defaults you could also just have all the variables under `defaults`. They are at the lowest level of precedence so they could be replaced by any of the other variables.

Comment: Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my answer? If it's wrong I'd like to know why so I stop doing it.....

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, so don't want to speak on their behalf, but maybe because it doesn't really answer the question.  It's a fine pattern and a valid approach.  But my case was I wanted default values for files where the defaults have a common parent but each/any file variable can be overridden when calling the playbook independently, with a full path.  So they might not be in the same parent folder if overridden

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: OK, so I can do it if i make them separate variables, just not if it's a single variable which is an object?  I'll try that.

Comment: Was it helpful at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with YAML anchors and references:

```yaml
scripts_config: 
  host_entry:
    dir: &basedir "/foo"
    bar: "{{ ref.basedir }}/bar"

ref:
  basedir: *basedir
```

With `&basedir` you create an anchor and with `*basedir` you reference it.

---

An alternative would be to define the value directly somewhere else:

```yaml
scripts_config: 
  host_entry:
    dir: "{{ ref.basedir }}"
    bar: "{{ ref.basedir }}/bar"

ref:
  basedir: "/foo"
```

Comment: Yeah, but those are not within the variable itself.  The `ref` is a separate variable from the `scripts_config`

Comment: Yes, my solution is a workaround. There simply is no way to use `{{ scripts_config.host_entry.dir }}` directly in `scripts_config.host_entry.bar`. By using YAML anchors and references, it is easy to understand and the value itself is still at its original position. But the downside of having something like `ref` is a valid point.